# Want to capture data from hyper terminal with C# web service

Tags: c#, web-services, hyperterminal

I am working on Hyper terminal to capture the data from Com1 port. I have configured it and the file I have is .ht file on the desktop where I can open and see the data.

The device that connected is a weight scale device. I can capture the data through hyper terminal and save it to a text file. But it is a continuous capturing and saving to that text file.

I am developing a web service in C# to get the weight data from hyper terminal. All I need from web service is to get the weight data from the scale when I want to.

I am thinking the way I can accomplish this is I have to turn on the hyper terminal, capture the data and turn off the hyper terminal. But I don't know how can I do this in C#.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. and please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: HyperTerminal is simply reading from the COM port. You would need to do the same with the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need hyper terminal. You can use [`System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class to communicate with COM ports